# can i use skype or facebook emoticons in my android app?

Tags: android, emoticons

I downloaded their emoticons and it is a silly question maybe but can I use them in my application for sending SMS messages. Or I need some license for that? What emoticons I can use without license? I'm asking that because I don't want someone to report my application for rights violations. Is that even possible for using emoticons, to get reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our laws you can use the icons in your application as long as you change them. You can use them as a blue print but may not copy them straight into your app. Although when it becomes a free app is may be less of an issue but this depends on your local laws.